# Goodreads api request requires Oauth rather than developer key, but returns 401 error when logged in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the passport goodreads strategy in my nodejs/express server to authenticate a user. Once logged in they should be able to add books to their shelves on my site, and retrieve info on the books. Currently I can access info using the developer key Goodreads provides, but for api post/get requests that say "this uses oauth" i get a 401 error everytime, even though I successfully log in with the passport strategy.

Example:
Get friend requests
Returns a XML with the current user's friend requests 'using OAuth. You'll need to register your app (required). 
URL: https://www.goodreads.com/friend/requests.xml 
HTTP method: GET 
Parameters: 
page: 1-N page of results to show (optional, default 1)

For that I have:

```
app.get('/api/friendrequests', async(req,res) => {


        var friendreqs = await 
            axios.get('https://www.goodreads.com//friend/requests.xml');
            console.log(friendreqs+'friendreqs');


    })
```

Am i missing something I should do?

Passport goodreads:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoodReadsStrategy = require('passport-goodreads');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const util = require('util');

const User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.serializeUser((user,done) => {

    //console.log('serialized');
    done(null, user.id);

})


passport.deserializeUser((id,done) => {

    //console.log('deserialized');
    User.findById(id).then(user => {

        done(null, user);

    })

})


passport.use(


    new GoodReadsStrategy(

    {

        consumerKey: keys.GOODREADS_KEY,
        consumerSecret: keys.GOODREADS_SECRET,
        callbackURL:'/auth/goodreads/callback',
        proxy:true

    },

    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

        //console.log(util.inspect(profile,false,null,true) + 'hi im profile now ehehe');

        try{

            const existingUser = await User.findOne({ goodreadId: profile.id });

            if(existingUser){
                return done(null, existingUser);
            }

            const user = await new User({

                goodreadId: profile.id,


            }).save();

            done(null, user);

        }catch(err){

            done(err, null);
        }




    }


        )
    )
```

Comment: I think their API is just a pile of dysfunctional shit, tbh. Has been for years it seems from their dev discussion forum.

Comment: Hope this will help https://github.com/intmainreturn00/grapi this libs works for me with OAuth